# In wordpress any option to find is blog

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

Is there any option to check `is blog page?`? in **Wordpress**.

I need to check this option. Help me.

Thanks...

Comment: No, but if you see http://wordpress.org/support/topic/is-there-a-is_blog and http://www.poseidonwebstudios.com/web-development/check-if-page-is-post-or-blog-page-in-wordpress/ they might give you a clue

Comment: Do you mean "is page" or "is blog post"? - they are different in Wordpress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `is_home()`

is_home() 
When the main blog page is being displayed. This is the page which shows the time based blog content of your site, so if you've set a static Page for the Front Page (see below), then this will only be true on the Page which you set as the "Posts page" in Administration > Settings > Reading. 
Taken from [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Comment: thanks. It's working fine. In future it's give any problem?? just for confirmation...

Comment: Glad I could help. Not that I am aware of. Don't forget to accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a page is actually a Wordpress page, use `is_page()` function.

- `is_page( 'About Me And Joe' )` - When the Page with a post_title of "About Me And Joe" is being displayed.
- `is_page( 'about-me' )` - When the Page with a post_name (slug) of "about-me" is being displayed.

To check if a given page is homepage, use `is_home()` function. `is_home()` checks for the "Posts Page".

```
if (is_home()) { 
//it's the homepage! 
}
```

If you have a static page set as home, then you need:

```
if (is_page('Home')){
//it's the homepage again
}
```

Documentation: [**`is_page()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)